# ID3 returns null - ActionScript

Tags: flash, actionscript, id3

```
var sound:Sound;
var url:URLRequest=new URLRequest("http://XXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
sound = new Sound();
var context:SoundLoaderContext=new SoundLoaderContext(0,false);
sound.addEventListener(Event.ID3, id3Handler);
sound.load(url,context);

var channel:SoundChannel = sound.play();

playB.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToPlayStopSound_2);

var fl_ToPlay_2:Boolean = false;

function id3Handler(event:Event):void 
{
    var id3:ID3Info = sound.id3;
    trace(id3.songName);
}

function fl_ClickToPlayStopSound_2(evt:MouseEvent):void
{
    if(fl_ToPlay_2)
    {
        sound = new Sound();
    sound.addEventListener(Event.ID3, id3Handler);
        sound.load(url,context);
        channel = sound.play();
        trace(sound.id3.songName);
        trace(sound.id3.artist);
    }
    else
    {
        channel.stop();
        sound.close();
    }
    fl_ToPlay_2 = !fl_ToPlay_2;
}
```

Im developing a player for my online radio (audio stream). "playB" its my play/stop button, and it works as intended. My problem is with the id3 tags...as u can see im doing a trace of the songname and artist but they all return null. (i already added the songname id3 to the files)

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to wait for the `sound` object to load before you can access its data. The `load()` method is asynchronous, which means you need to add an event listener to know when the load has completed:

```
public function Sound_id3Example()
{
    snd.addEventListener(Event.ID3, id3Handler);
    snd.load(new URLRequest("mySound.mp3"));
}

private function id3Handler(event:Event):void 
{
    var id3:ID3Info = snd.id3;
    trace(id3.songName);
}
```

There is an example of how to do this in the [Adobe Actionscript documentation for Sound::id3](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Sound.html#id3)

Comment: and where would i call the Sound_id3Example() ?
anyways, i added the id3Handle function, and called sound.addEventListener(Event.ID3, id3Handler); before the sound.load. It never gets into the id3Handler function

Comment: im gona edit the main post with the current code i have.